# LINQ Expressions: the Nreco Framework give compile error

Tags: c#, linq, nuget, nreco

It is the first time I use nuget and I am trying to compile a dynamic lambda parser example from [NRecoFramework](https://www.nrecosite.com/nrecoframework/common_library_net.aspx) as shown below:

```
    var lambdaParser = new NReco.LambdaParser();
    var varContext = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    varContext["one"] = 1M;
    varContext["two"] = "2";

    Console.WriteLine(lambdaParser.Eval("two>one && 0<one ? (1+8)/3+1*two : 0", varContext)); // --> 5`
```

but when I try to compile, the `LamdaParser()` method is not recognized.

I have already imported the nuget and nreco frameworks to VisualStudio2017 but it still doesn't compile.

[Print of My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsTrd.png)

***SOLVED***

My bad, the problem was that I had imported both the [Nreco Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco/) and  [Nreco.LambdaParser Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.LambdaParser/), as the LamdaParser() method exits at both packages I was unable to compile. After removing Nreco.LamdaParser package the problem was solved.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Roger! If you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: Please do not edit your answer into the question - that is what the answers section is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the example on the framework site is either outdated or simply wrong.
Their [API documentation](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco/) is up to date.

The `LambdaParser` is in the `NReco.Linq` namespace. You'll need to change your code to:

```
var lambdaParser = new NReco.Linq.LambdaParser();
var varContext = new Dictionary<string, object>();
varContext["one"] = 1M;
varContext["two"] = "2";

Console.WriteLine(lambdaParser.Eval("two>one && 0<one ? (1+8)/3+1*two : 0", varContext)); // --> 5`
```

Or, since you have a `using NReco.Linq;` declaration in your file, you can also write:

```
var lambdaParser = new LambdaParser();
var varContext = new Dictionary<string, object>();
varContext["one"] = 1M;
varContext["two"] = "2";

Console.WriteLine(lambdaParser.Eval("two>one && 0<one ? (1+8)/3+1*two : 0", varContext)); // --> 5`
```

Comment: My bad, the problem was that I had imported both the Nreco package and the Nreco.LambdaParser Package, as the LamdaParser methos exits at both I was unable to compile. After removing the Nreco.LamdaParser package the problem was solved.

Comment: @RogerMoschiel as library author I recommend to use "NReco.LambdaParser" nuget package which contains _only_ LambdaParser functionality. Legacy "NReco" nuget package is outdated and not supported any more (and will be unlisted from nuget.org in future).